# calling a dispatcher to cancel a MVVM property change does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a MVVM property to update and there are some situations where I want to cancel the change inside the setter.

I have read several SO posts explaining that we need to use a dispatcher to do this:

- [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27449797/wpf-mvvm-light-cancel-property-change-in-viewmodel-raisepropertychanged-even)
- [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608071/wpf-cancel-a-user-selection-in-a-databound-listbox)

However, it does not work in my case.
For any reason, the XAML control still updates.
I am confused as I can see the debugger run the dispatcher method after the properrty is set to the new value. It does run the code that should switch it back, but the control sticks to the new value instead of switching back to the old one.

My code is as follows:

```
    private DB_VisionParameters _MyProp;
    public DB_VisionParameters MyProp
    {
        get
        {
            return _MyProp;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_MyProp == value)
            {
                return;
            }


            if ( isInvalidTest)
            {
              MyType storedValue = _MyProp;
                //switch back to update interface with old value
               DB_VisionParameters previousVisionParameter = _MyProp;
                if (DispatcherHelper.UIDispatcher != null)
                    DispatcherHelper.UIDispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                    (new Action(() =>
                    {
                        _MyProp = storedValue;
                        RaisePropertyChanged("MyProp");
                    })), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);

                return;                    
            }

            _MyProp = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("MyProp");
        }
    }
```

Looks like SO solutions to me but I have probably missed something :(

Comment: Are you sure in Dispatcher method: MyProp = storedValue;
is getting the old value ?
Can you also ensure no one else is updating the same instance of object.

Comment: @Versatile 
actually both  MyProp and storedValue have the old value in debug mode. The line is useless but that was just to make sure.

I put a breakpoint in the property setter and nothing else updates it.
I am really puzzled with this one.

Comment: Actually you were right.
This was not working at first because MyProp was modified by an object implementing INotifyPropertyChanged  which was causing hassle.
Once sorted, the dispatcher works exactly as expected! Thox for having pointed me into the right direction.

Comment: Don't forget to mark it as an answer as it resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and if MyProp has the right value (i.e. the old value) and if it is not modified by anyone else then it should update.
As you have also confirmed the same that you had it being modified in your version of code thus the instance was never the same and it reflected with newer version details on UI, which was not as expected.